# Array index loop variable resets to zero in C, C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have declared an array of length N (suppose). Now, I assign some values to the elements of this array using a loop (the loop variable is used as the array's index). The code's as follows:

```
int main()
{
  int arr[4], j;
  for(j=0; j<10; j++)
  {     
    printf("%d\n", j);
    arr[j] = 0;
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d\n\n", j);
  } 
return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 0 1 2 .. 9. But what actually happened was that j got reset to 0 when the assignment arr[N+2]=0 (arr[6]=0, in this case) was executed in the loop.
What's actually happening here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your array has 4 elements and your index is out of range so you are just stomping on memory.

Given the code here, I'd expect `arr[4]` to reset the array, but since you mentioned that it's of length `N` and `N+2` is what causes it, there might be some padding in your stack.  In any case, when you declare the array and `j`, they are put on the stack.  In your case, `j` is in a position such that when your index is out of bounds you are accessing the memory where `j` is.

Comment: What do you mean by stomping here?

Comment: I updated the answer.  Basically arr[N] is the same thing as adding N to the pointer to the beginning of the array and dereferencing the memory.  It doesn't care if arr's length is smaller -- that's up to you to check.  As soon as you assign to an out-of-bounds array element, you are stomping on memory -- all bets are off now. Program could crash, launch missiles, reset j, increase radiation levels, spin centrifuges out of control, etc.

Comment: Once you access an array out of bounds, anything can happen. So, yes, it's undefined.  You can't even read it without possibly crashing.  On Windows you sometimes see an error message when an application crashes that says "Protected memory error 0x48239483 cannot be read" -- this error is because the memory location that was accidentally read isn't mapped to the process (is protected).

Answer (score 3):

the behaviour of the code is undefined as it has a bug. arr has a size of 4 but you are indexing past this size with j

Answer (score 2):

Your array is overflowing.  You defined it like this with 4 elements:

```
int arr[4]
```

But you're trying to assign 10 elements.

`j` is apparently located immediately after the array, so when you assign `arr[6] = 0`, you're clearing `j`.

Comment: That's be my though. I don't know about compiler or language dynamics, but if I had to guess, I would assume that J would be created in the first memory location after the array, which would mean when you write to arr[4] you might be over writing j.

Comment: But isn't it legal to dereference the first memory location beyond the array's last element? I mean this location is reserved, isn't it?

Comment: "Illegal" means that if you break your side of the contract, the compiler is no longer bound to do your bidding. It becomes its own master and demons possess your nostrils.

Comment: You may legally **create a pointer to** the first memory location beyond the array's last element, and **compare it to** pointers that are actually pointing into the array; but you may not dereference it. To do so is undefined behaviour. There is **no** guarantee in C++ about the order of objects in memory, beyond ordering that you impose yourself; pointers to different objects/arrays shall not mix; and the memory immediately beyond an object doesn't necessarily even belong to your program. Creating a "one past the end" pointer is just to make it easier to iterate over an array with a pointer.